# Non-square NSButton

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

How to create a NSButton with non-square "hit area"?

Example:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I found exactly what I need here: http://www.harmless.de/cocoa-code.php AMShapedButton class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably subclass NSButton and override `hitTest:` to return nil when outside the area you want to be clickable. (Return `[super hitTest:]` when inside.)

[Docs here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/hitTest%3a)