# Is there NSButton overlaps solutions?

Tags: objective-c, nsbutton

I try to put some buttons with different images or form and the problem is when the buttons are too close they are overlapping.

[image]

The idea is only the image of button need to respond when I perform click and transparent part ignored

Is there some solutions for that?

---

**Ok after 1 hour reading some post here and apple doc I find solution**

what is needed:

- NSButton(s) without border
- NSButton Custom Class
- Buttons need to point to our Custom NSButton Class
- Some code ....

here is the code who make the button respond only if I perform click on button image and ignore event/clicks outside where our button is transparent.

This code need to put it in our NSButton Custom Class in "OurNSButtonCustomClass.m"

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}

- (BOOL)isOpaque{
    return NO;
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {

    NSPoint cursorLocation = [event locationInWindow];
    cursorLocation = [self convertPoint:cursorLocation fromView:nil];

    // Test if the hit occured in the opaque part of the image.  We create a 1x1 rectange at the click point and test for intersection with a non-transparent section of the image.
    NSRect cursorLocationRect = { cursorLocation, {1, 1} };
    if ( [self.image hitTestRect:cursorLocationRect withImageDestinationRect:self.bounds
                         context:nil hints:nil flipped:NO] == YES ) {
        // If the click missed then we ignore it here.
        [super mouseDown:event];
        return;
    }
}
```

---

OR instead of mouse event

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event

we can use hitTest function:

```
-(NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint{

    NSRect myRect= { [self convertPoint:aPoint fromView:nil] ,1,1};

    if([self.image hitTestRect:myRect withImageDestinationRect:self.bounds
                        context:nil hints:nil flipped:NO]){

        return [super hitTest:aPoint];

    }

    return nil;
}
```

---

That's it. This work for me.

**One more thing:**
 IF the buttons images are overlapped for some strange design the type of buttons need to be "**Momentary Change**", if they are "**Momentary push In**" this may cause **isOpaque=YES** effect when the button is pushed!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-square NSButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313938/non-square-nsbutton)

Comment: yes this helped me to find the solution, there are some class and they work, but they are more completed and complicated. I just need the base the method without any functions and extras. Thanks for the fast comment.